# Extract lines in CSV file which don't have elements in a list

Tags: python, regex, list, csv, tokenize

I have a list with substrings which  I need to compare with a column in CSV file if any of the substring present in the list is present in that column of a CSV file. I would like to write those lines which don't have those substrings in that string column. There are many columns in this file and I am looking only in one column.

Example my_string column has values

```
{ "This is just comparison of likely tokens","what a tough thing?"}

de = ["just","not","really ", "hat"]
```

I would like to write only the row which has "What a tough thing?"

This works fine if there is only the word in the list in the column. For instance if the my_string column has "really" it will not write to new file. But, it can't pass if item in list comes with other strings.

```
with open(infile, 'rb') as inFile, open(outfile, 'wb') as outfile:
reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')

for row[1] in reader:

    if any(d in row[1] for d in de):
        pass
    else:
        writer.writerow(row[1])
```

Comment: can you post a sample data set from your CSV  and desired output? BTW i would suggest to use pandas module if performance does matter...

Comment: Your example's syntax is invalid and doesn't define `readrow` but it is similar to a script that should work. Can you post a working example and how that example fails?

Comment: @tdelaney thanks that was my typo as I was experimenting something else and forgot to change back. this is the original code and works fine, but isn't able to match if the string has words along with substring present in list de.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile the words into a single regex, and even do case insensitive match as follows:

```
r = re.compile('\\b('+"|".join(de)+')\\b', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Then your code could simply be:

```
with open(infile, 'rb') as inFile, open(outfile, 'wb') as outfile:
reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')

for row in reader:
    if not r.search(row[1]):
        writer.writerow(row[1])
```

Comment: thank you! this is somehow splitting the words into letters which I don't want. I want to make sure it copies all columns for only the strings that are not present in list. thank you!

Comment: np. Not sure what you mean by splitting words into letters though. The regular expression will be of the form r'\b(just|not|really|hat)\b', which will match any of the whole words in the list; the '\b' is the word boundary symbol. Try and see for yourself.

Comment: this is actually what I would like to do. but somehow that regex line gives me unbounded parenthesis error. I try to fix it but I still get another error - unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'; when I modified r = re.compile("\\b('+"|".join(de)+')\\b", re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: I think you have an extra quote, use this:

    r = re.compile('\\b('+"|".join(de)+')\\b', re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: I still get unbalanced parenthesis error when I use it.

Comment: I've tried it on command line and on jupyter notebook. Perhaps you are using an editor that changes the quotes, because the one you've pasted had extra quotes.

Comment: I am really sorry, you are correct. It was my python notebook editor which had the issue. I tried in another machine with jupyter and it worked perfectly. This is what I was looking. Great answer. Thank you so much. I will use this even though I was doing a long way.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a string is present in a list of substrings, I generally use sets.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['c','d','e']
```

Now, to find the difference,

```
list3 = list(set(a) - set(b))
```

which gives you ['a','b'] (what's in list1 that's not in list2) and there you have the strings that you are interested in. Doing

```
list(set(b) - set(a))
```

would give you the strings for "what is in list2 that is not in list1?", namely ['e','d']

Comment: thanks for the answer but both are not list. And, I can't do this. One is a line with a long string value present as one of the column value from CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to search for words instead of just substrings so that, for instance, "hat" won't match "What". Word searches can get complicated when want to match plurals, different cases, hyphenated strings and so on. But if you don't mind ignoring those complications, you can use a regex to break the column into a list of words, lower case them and then use set operations for the check.

```
import re
import csv

# TEST: write a sample csv file. using col0 to indicate what should be
# in the outfile
open('infile.csv', 'w').write(
"""exclude,This is just a comparison of likely tokens,col02,col03
include,what a tough thing?,col12,col13""")

# the words to find
de = ["just","not","really", "hat"]

# the files
infile = 'infile.csv'
outfile = 'outfile.csv'

# a "normalized set" of words to search
de = set(word.lower() for word in de)

def normalize_text(text):
    """Return a set of all the words in lowercased text"""
    return set(re.findall('\w+', text.lower()))

with open(infile, 'r') as inFile, open(outfile, 'w') as outFile:
    reader = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')
    writer = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        mycol = normalize_text(row[1])
        if not mycol & de:
            writer.writerow(row)

print("---- output file ----")
print(open(outfile).read())
```

Comment: thank you so much. can't thank you enough. A QQ is there a way I could include some symbols as well in words. Example I want to match "really_tokens" with "really" as well. thanks much.

Comment: yes, the regex could be `r"[\w_\-]" to include slashes and underscores for instance. Notice the raw string and the backslashes to escape characters that have other meanings in the regex.